# Extend outter element in firefox to include inner element

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, firefox, gecko

I'm working on this [landing page](http://deeboost.com/) and I have an issue with the section on the top( the one with the background picture with the sun at dawn)

On Chrome I managed to place the tablet image inside the background section, but on Firefox the background section doesn't extend itself to include the tablet image.

Do you have any ideas on how can I fix it?

Comment: It's being caused by margin collapsing and the fact that your tablet thing is`pos:rel`'d down rather than actually existing where it displays, fairly sure. Move the `margin` on `.container.content` into its `padding`.

Answer (score 2):

### The problem

Margin collapsing means the `margin` on your `.container.content` is technically supposed to be outside the parent, not inside, as nothing gets in the way of collapsing the `margin-bottom` on `.container.content`

The background image is not stretched over the margin, so the collapsed `margin` (which is now property of `.bg` since `.bg-color` will collapse its `margin-bottom` upwards as well) peeks through to the actual background of the page- that cream color you see.

Also, fun fact, I'm pretty sure this means that *Chrome is rendering it wrong.*<sup>Shots Fired</sup>

Further reading on Margin Collapsing can be found at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing).

---

### The solution

Easiest, just change the current:

```
.guests_pages .bg .bg-color .container.content{
    margin:0 auto 10%;
}
```

to

```
.guests_pages .bg .bg-color .container.content{
    margin:0 auto;
    padding-bottom:10%;
}
```

Padding doesn't collapse, so it can't pass it up and must now stretch the parent rather than let the parent claim it as its own.

Comment: `the margin on your .container.content is technically supposed to be outside the parent` Isn't that how the Box model works in general? I don't see the relation with margin collapsing?

Comment: @user3790827 If not for margin collapsing, that margin would be inside the parent, and Firefox would display how Chrome was displaying. Margin Collapsing (which is part of the box model) is why the last (only) child's `margin-bottom` is attached to the parent in Firefox, rather than stretching the parent like it does in Chrome.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure of the reason, but I suspect it's something to do with the how the ::before and ::after selectors being interpreted slightly differently by the browsers.

One workaround would be to increase the min-height on the .bg selector and add min-height to the .bg-color selector. I appreciate that it would be better to understand the reason for the rendering difference, but this did at least resolve the issue when manually tweaking the CSS via Firebug.

Comment: It's actually related to margin collapsing, just thought you might wanna know (since you expressed uncertainty).

Comment: Ah, that's good to know - I appreciate you commenting so I could see the solution! It was a bit of a head scratcher :)